# Storing data in an array and pushing items down with a for-loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, store

I am not sure how to make this method push items down instead of overwrite them. Right now, if I have an array of 10 items:

```
[0] = zero
[1] = one
[2] = two
...
[10] = ten
```

and I insert an item at index [2], what happens is the following:

```
[0] = zero
[1] = one
[2] = two
[3] = two
[4] = two
 ...  
[10] = two
```

It overwrites all items after the selected index, instead of push them down by an index. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Thanks.

```
public void insert(int i, String s) {

if (array[i] == null) {
    array[i] = s;spot on the list.
} else { 
    for (int j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
        array[j + 1] = array[j]; 

        if (j == array.length - 1) { 
            break;
        } 
    }
    array[i] = s;
    extendArray();
```

Comment: Try debbuging it. It will help you learn java more easily...

Comment: You realize that in Java arrays don't automatically resize, so if your program ever enters into `if (array[i] == null) {array[i] = s;}` then your program will crash.  You have to create a new array of increased size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing the changed indices.

"array[j + 1] = array[j]; "
after you changed array[j] (which is == to array[i] at the beginning of the for loop).

But look at this:

ar = [1,2,3]

Inserting in position 1 means I'll make ar[2]=ar[1].

How to do it? Pull instead of push. Make the loop go down from array.length-1 to the index you want to change.

```
//check if you need to grow the array first.
for (int j = array.length-1; j > i; j--) {
    array[j] = array[j-1]; 
}
//and now insert.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "push" items instead of "overwriting" them, then you shouldn't use an array, this job is easier using an `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lst.add(1);
lst.add(3);
lst.add(4);
lst.add(1, 2); // "push" the elements to the right, making room for 2
```

In the above example, at the end `lst` will contain `1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: The question is regarding the algorithm, though, so... wouldn't make much sense to use a data structure which makes the algorithm useless. Besides, what do you think the ArrayList does internally?

Comment: @iajrz in any real production system, you would never write this algorithm yourself.

Comment: @iajrz _precisely_, why reinvent the wheel, if `ArrayList` does exactly the same, under the hood?

Comment: Didn't imply that. And neither did the OP. The question was "I am not sure how to make _this method_ push items down instead of overwrite them.". But it's OK... I just hoped you'd answer the question _and_ counsel, not just counsel.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: you mean to tell me you never, even once, wrote a sorting algorithm? Or a search algorithm? or a tree balancing algorithm? There's a reason to do it: to learn!

Comment: @ljrz it all depends on OP's expectations. If he/she is writing this method as part of a homework for a course then yes, your point of view is perfectly valid. On the other hand, from a practical point of view, my suggestion is more useful. Let's not argue among ourselves, let OP choose the best answer for him/her, and anyway the other answers will be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your replacement :

```
 array[j + 1] = array[j];
```

Take an example : if you are with `j = 0` then you replace `array[1]` with the value in `array[0]`
Then on the next step of your loop you replace the value of `array[2]` with the value of `array[1]` which has been replaced by the value of `array[0]`.

You should process your array starting by the end (decreasing `j` from `array.length` to `j=i`) and you should be fine.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can change the for-loop condition

From

```
for (int j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++) {

            array[j + 1] = array[j];
```

To

```
for(int j=array.length-2;j>=i;j--){

            array[j + 1] = array[j];
```

With this change, the following information will be displaying in Console:

```
[zero, one, two, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine]
```